# How to decode URL parameter using AngularJS or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a value that I pass on to URL parameter the original value looks like this:

```
1436641259169/nDfmDmVa
```

when it gets passed on it converts it to this:

```
1436641259169%252FnDfmDmVa
```

So, how to do I convert it back when I pull it down?

Answer (score 14):

This may help you: [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

```
decodeURIComponent(string);
```

Example:

```
decodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent("1436641259169%252FnDfmDmVa"))
> "1436641259169/nDfmDmVa"
```

Comment: You might explain why you're decoding it twice. In any case, the OP's original is *very* string. `decodeURIComponent` might be *part* of the answer, but not the whole answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Um, [yes](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tVvGO.png) though it is kind of weird that I need to pass it through twice. The question definitely says decoding URL parameter but the string in the question is not actually correct.

Comment: @teddybear123 It should work according to your question. If not, you might want to be a little bit more detailed on what the conversion is. `decodeURIComponent` is supposed to, well, decode URI components.

Comment: @teddybear123: "Didn't work" is not a useful problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you to decode the url :

```
  decode(content: string){
    return decodeURIComponent(content);
  }
```